# Populate UITableViewController

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, uiimageview

Here is the code were I print contents to the table view

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "atmCell", for: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel?.text = AtmList.instance.atms[indexPath.row].title
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = AtmList.instance.atms[indexPath.row].subtitle
    cell.imageView?.setImage = "Icon\(([indexPath.row] as! String)").imgPoi



    return cell
}
```

I would like to use the title to printed on the tableview to compare with the name in which images were saved in assets and populate the table view accordingly.

Here is an image of the view controller.
[view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVcNm.png)

Comment: I am not getting that what issue you are facing.

Comment: I am trying to use the images saved in my project assets that have the e same name as the title to populate the image view on the list. The titles are generated by google places. So say the title is Zen bank. I have an image saved with ZenBank and i want it to display beside the title on the tableview @JogendarChoudhary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
     position = place.coordinate

    //Adding icons to maps as atm pinpoints
    if place.name[place.name.startIndex] == "W" {
        icon = UIImage(named: "wemaBank_pin")// takes a Character or a literal
    }else if  place.name[place.name.startIndex] == "A"  {
        icon = UIImage(named: "AccessBank_pin")
    }else if  place.name[place.name.startIndex] == "C"  {
        icon = UIImage(named: "CitiBank_pin")
    }else if  place.name[place.name.startIndex] == "D"  {
        icon = UIImage(named: "DiamondBank_pin")
    }else if  place.name[place.name.startIndex] == "H"  {
        icon = UIImage(named: "HeritageBank_Pin")
    }else if  place.name[place.name.startIndex] == "P"  {
        icon = UIImage(named: "ProvidusBank_pin")
    } else if  place.name[place.name.startIndex] == "F" &&  place.name[place.name.index(place.name.startIndex, offsetBy: 2)] == "D" {
        icon = UIImage(named: "FidelityBank_pin")
    }else if  place.name[place.name.startIndex] == "F" &&  place.name[place.name.index(after: place.name.startIndex)] == "C" {
            icon = UIImage(named: "FCMB_pin")
    } else if  place.name[place.name.startIndex] == "F" &&  place.name[place.name.index(place.name.startIndex, offsetBy: 5)] == "C" {
        icon = UIImage(named: "FCMB_pin")
    } else if  place.name[place.name.startIndex] == "U" &&  place.name[place.name.index(place.name.startIndex, offsetBy: 3)] == "o" {
        icon = UIImage(named: "UnionBank_pin")
    }else if  place.name[place.name.startIndex] == "G"  {
        icon = UIImage(named: "GTBank_pin")
    }else if  place.name[place.name.startIndex] == "G" &&  place.name[place.name.index(place.name.startIndex, offsetBy: 1)] == "U" {
        icon = UIImage(named: "GTBank_pin")
    }else if  place.name[place.name.startIndex] == "F"  {
        icon = UIImage(named: "FirstBank_pin")
    }else if  place.name[place.name.startIndex] == "K"  {
        icon = UIImage(named: "KeystoneBank_pin")
    }else if  place.name[place.name.startIndex] == "S" && place.name[place.name.index(place.name.startIndex, offsetBy: 2)] == "y" {
        icon = UIImage(named: "skyeBank_pin")
    }else if  place.name[place.name.startIndex] == "E"  {
        icon = UIImage(named: "ecoBank_pin")
    }else if  place.name[place.name.startIndex] == "Z"  {
        icon = UIImage(named: "ZenithBank_pin")
    }else if  place.name[place.name.startIndex] == "U" &&  

       groundAnchor = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 1)
      appearAnimation = .pop
        }
      }
```